# Is AJAX enough? Should I learn a PHP framework?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I started learning programming 4 months ago. So far I already know some javascript(and jquery), php, ajax html and CSS. Yesterday I saw for the first time in one of the stack forums a question about PHP frameworks (zend, codeigniter...etc).

I hope these questions are not very stupid, because I am a beginner so I don't know much about this world yet, but my questions are:
1- Do I need to learn how to use a php framework if I just one to build **ONE** website?
2- Do websites nowadays rely more on AJAX + some php OR just PHP + some javascript?
3- How long does it take to learn and master a php framework like zend?

Comment: For 2, The client side of AJAX is just a particular subset of Javascript  ;)

Comment: CodeIgniter is easier than Zend. If your site uses a DB, I would use a framework, just be sure to READ THE DOCS before you start to keep things DRY. If you understand PHP syntax and the basics of OO programming, you can probably start coding in CI right away and figure the rest out as you go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You don't *need* to learn a PHP framework, and in fact if it's the first website you've ever built I'd suggest building it without a framework just to get a feel for how PHP works when building a site. This way you understand things like database connections, session management, etc. that is often done behind the scenes with frameworks. Then later on try building it with a framework to get an idea for the design patterns and other features that a framework has built-in to avoid code repetition, security holes, etc.

2) I don't know what the difference between AJAX + some PHP and just PHP + some javascript. AJAX is a part of Javascript, it isn't a separate technology on its own.

Some websites use a lot of AJAX, some don't. It really depends on what you want the website to do and your particular design: AJAX can provide a smoother feel to the site, but can have complications when it comes to things like back buttons and bookmarks.

3) Depends on what you're doing with the framework: if you're only using 10% of the features you certainly won't become a master in any amount of time. It also depends on the complexity of the framework: I haven't used Zend but I know that the more complex the framework, the longer it will take you to learn it.

Comment: Thanks a lot robbrit, i will take this into account. I won't use a framework for the first website then.

Answer (score 2):

Learn as many thing as you can. PHP is a good start, becouse it's very popular and easy to learn and use. There are many great frameworks written in PHP (Symfony, Zend, Kohana, etc.). However, it's not a nice, well designed language at all. Keep it in mind, don't stop at php, learn it then make progress.

b) You will be able to build a large variety of sites with PHP+JS+HTML

ps.: AJAX is a technology, and as a knowledge, it doesn't worth so much as is.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. I still have some doubts about your answer. When you say that "it is not a nice, well designed language" are you referring to PHP as a whole or to frameworks or to both? When you say "don't stop at PHP", what other languages/frameworks/techs do you recommend?

Comment: PHP <5.3 was pretty much terrible as a base language for building frameworks; it's only fairly recently that we've started getting all the tools that are needed to solve frameworking problems effectively.

Comment: It's PHP. It suffers from the design errors and mistakes of older versions. Despite of that, it's easy to use, and the mentoined frameworks built on the top of PHP are really powerful when it comes to build a larger website. Other languages: an easy one: Python. Some harder: C/C++, Java

Answer (score 2):

1. Ajax is just a technology to call server side scripts from Javascript. The server side script being PHP. So, if you intend to use Ajax, you need to know PHP.
2. As for PHP frameworks, its good to build a few website from scratch using PHP to get a better understanding, but eventually, its better to adopt frameworks. Frameworks implement a lot of the functions and methods you need. No point re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: In number 1, although I'm sure this is what @xbonez meant, you don't need PHP specifically; I imagine he just meant to describe the scenario according to the fact that you've already pre-selected PHP as the server-side language.

Comment: Late response, but @GregPettit is right, you're not bound to use PHP as your server side script. Any server side script would work (Ruby, Python, Java, ASP.NET etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The answers to your questions are very subjective, but what I suggest is:

1. No you should not learn a framework to build one website. Just go and build it in any way you can. Frameworks usually carry a lot of additional concepts and methodologies. You will have to invest quite some time to understand how they work, but it will be really hard to understand why they work that way. Doing a website is a great experience, so just go and build something.
2. Lets say websites mostly rely on HTML / PHP / JavaScript. Ajax is just an additional capability, which you are already focusing too much. It's great that you know what Ajax does, but you should concentrate more on the essential things, like number one.
3. Lets say it takes two years of constant interest in the field. So at first you learn the syntax of PHP, then you start to know how HTTP works, then you experiment with HTML and JavaScript/jQuery/Ajax a bit more, then you try a Framework. You keep trying until you become a master. Zend Framework is one of the most comprehensive, so it will take a while to study how it works and all the related technologies it brings with it.

My final advice is to stay focused, build something, see what challenges it brings, solve those challenges and eventually become a master. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot Vilius, i will take this into account. I won't use a framework for the first website then.

Answer (score 1):

Question One - The short answer is: it depends on the type of site you're building. The frameworks you're talking about were built to streamline web *application* development, which make extensive use of databases and object-oriented principles. If you're planning on building a site with mostly static content, I wouldn't bother learning a framework just yet.

Question Two - Again, it depends on the site. The concept of AJAX has many applications, but most sites employ it to make a site more interactive (e.g. not refreshing the page to load new content). For sites with primarily static content, AJAX has fewer uses.

Question Three - It can take a while to 'master' a framework. I'm not that familiar with the ones you mentioned, but learning a framework is less about understanding it's syntax/quirks and more about learning how to approach a problem *their way*. Again, it depends on what you're doing.